# Android Facebook not asking for different user login in app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, logout, android-facebook

I am developing an application in which i am having Facebook authentication on custom button. The code i done is as follows:

First i initialize facebook SDK in my activity onCreate() as:

```
// Facebook
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
```

then i registered call back as:

```
// Facebook Login
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                // Get facebook data from login
                try {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    String id = object.getString("id");

                    URL profile_pic = null;
                    try {
                        profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                        bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                    String lastName = object.getString("last_name");

                     } catch(JSONException e) {
                         Log.d("FB","Error parsing JSON");
                     }
                 }
             });

             Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
             parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
             request.setParameters(parameters);
             request.executeAsync();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancel() {
             Toast.makeText(LoginScreenActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
             Toast.makeText(LoginScreenActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });
```

And on my custom button click:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
```

And the on activity result code is :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Facebook
    if (mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

This works fine. I done the code of logout on other activity as :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

**The issue is:** When i tried to **login again** with facebook it is **not asking** me for **login with different credentials** of facebook user. App directly do the login with the previous login details.

What i am missing? What should i do now.

Please guide me. Thank you in advance for you valuable suggestions.

Comment: From FB's official docs read below : Apps should build their own mechanisms to switch between different Facebook user accounts using log out functions and should not rely upon re-authentication for this. The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently support re-authentication.

Comment: This is the link for the above said documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

Comment: @SudheeshR - Thank you for your reply. But i am not able to understand the docs. I am not getting the login popup.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did anyone found answer for this questions ?

Comment: when I m logout from my fb app , then going to login from app and choose login with fb then and then it displays select account dialog.